# Date in MySQL Laravel ORM

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, timestamp, laravel-5

I store my dates in `timestamp` type (and I see in PHPMyAdmin for simple `2015-04-14 00:00:00`). Is it stupid? Better way is set to `int` type and save UNIX time?

How can I do query

```
select * from `values` where `time` < $mytimeinunix
```

because `Model::all()->where('time','<',$mytimeinunix)` is not working.

Regards

Comment: First question: Why do you want to store them in a `TIMESTAMP` type? That's an ancient relic from MySQL 1.0. Why not `DATETIME`?

Comment: I'm not good in bases. If `DATETIME` is better I will use it :)

Comment: @tadman What? TIMESTAMP fields are not an ancient relic. They come in very handy when dealing with timezones.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html): "MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval." That's a convenience method only, and time-zone handling should be done in the application anyway where it can be client specific. Plus, they're bounded, they only work up to 2038, making them a ticking time bomb. Why would you voluntarily use them? Generally it's best to use the standard `DATETIME` or `DATE` unless you have a very specific reason.

Comment: @tadman They're fine for a variety of use cases. Laravel uses them for created_at/updated_at/deleted_at columns, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [UNIX_TIMESTAMP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp):

```
Model::where(DB::raw('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time)'), '<', $mytimeinunix)->get();
```

Comment: This won't perform very well as it can't be indexed.

Comment: I can't do it with in-build ORM? Sorry for my stupid question but I learn Laravel now :<

Comment: Limonte thanks it's working fine, thank You bro :) I will accept answer soon :)